# 2 divs on left 1 on right

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to get 2 divs to align on the left with one on the right.

```
#div1 #div2
#div1 #div2
#div3 #div2
#div3
#div3
```

the trick is I want #div2 to fall in between the #div1 and #div3 when the browser window is made smaller.

at the moment #div3 only starts after #div2 but correctly falls into place when the window is shrunk

```
#div1 #div2
#div1 #div2
      #div2
#div3
#div3
#div3
```

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ - jQuery Masonry is very good for sorting out boxes, I recommend you take a look

Comment: THanks but id like a css only solution if possible

Comment: could you show us your html? can't you put div1 and div3 in a common div?

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about doing that but the issue will be when I shrink the window(or use media queries for mobile) those to divs will be stuck together.

Comment: What have you done so far? At least a jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Questions like this have been asked many times before. I'm surprised it got any upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? (Manually shrink the viewport size to see the media query in action.)

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
<div id="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
<div id="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>​
```

CSS

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    width: 300px;
}

#div1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#div2 {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#div3 {
    border: 1px solid cyan;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#div2 {
    position: static;
}
}
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/z9AsG/

Answer (score 2):

If the Divs happen to have the same number of elements (such as 3 links and a "more" button for more links) and each line can be appended by the "Override: ellipsis" function so that each div is of equal height, you'd solve your problem.

Otherwise if Div 2 is the only one that shows up on the right hand you can set it up to be shown at a fixed position from the left.

I just tested it in a fiddle. I really despise doing this, because I think it takes it away from your ability to grow but alas, I hope you take this a learning example: http://jsfiddle.net/nugPA/

If you take this line out it goes back to a simple column:

```
div#two {position: fixed; left: 150px;}
```

Questions like this have been asked multiple times in the past.

Comment: Are the Divs of fixed height and width?

Comment: This can't be done by CSS alone. Unless you don't mind Div 2 being underneath Div 3 or above Div 1 in a media query layout

Comment: Actually, if Div 2 is the ONLY one that'll occur on the right side you could just use Fixed positioning. But I doubted that's the set up

Comment: it is the only one but wont it still push down the div3 if i make it fixed?

Comment: @davey No. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help victoroux but mdepoli nailed it in such a elegant way.

Comment: He added one line for a media query. Which I assumed you knew how to do. It's not "such an elegant way" as it is the only and same way with pure CSS!